# Read the file and split by the sum of words, upload to a folder

Tags: python, file, text, split, sum

I figured out how to count words, how to split them - how to combine + put a ***** mark at the end of a sentence for > 200 and < 250 words (after the dot)???

```
# text counting method

file = open("test.txt", "r")
number_of_lines = 0
number_of_words = 0
number_of_characters = 0

for line in file:
    line = line.strip("\n")
    words = line.split()
    number_of_lines += 1
    number_of_words += len(words)
    number_of_characters += len(line)

file.close()

print("lines:", number_of_lines, "words:", number_of_words, "characters:", number_of_characters, ( "sum_chsrters:", number_of_characters // 1000, "sum_wolds:", number_of_words // 120 ))

# text splitting method
with open('test.txt') as fo:
  op = ''
  start = 0
  cntr = 1
  for x in fo.read().split("\n"):
      if (x=='*****'):
          if (start==1):
              with open(str(cntr) + '.txt', 'w') as opf:
                  opf.write(op)
                  opf.close()
                  op=''
                  cntr+=1
          else:
              start=1
      else:
          if (op==''):
              op = x
          else:
              op = op + '\n' + x

  fo.close()
```

P.S - I'm a beginner. It needs to be split file (sum +10,000 characters) into 10 parts (1000 characters or 120 words each) and put in a folder (01.txt, 02.txt, ...,10.txt)

Comment: Hi, can you make it a bit clearer please, how you want to split the words into files?

Comment: Is it "10,000 characters or 1200 words each" at your option, or whichever comes first, or what?  A generator might be really nice here either way.

Comment: Thinking to put a "*****" mark at the end of a sentence for > 200 and < 250 words (after the end of the sentence ".")?  And cut into files by label "*****"